# User-defined function on large crossjoined dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to find the sum `dsum` of a user-defined function `calcd` run over a dataframe consisting of one or more columns containing a range of floats.  The dataframe is the Cartesian product of a given range across N columns.

For example, two-column input with the range {-5.0, -4.9, ..., 5.0} might be:

| x1 | x2 |
| --- | --- |
| -5.0 | -5.0 |
| -5.0 | -4.9 |
| ... | ... |
| 5.0 | 4.9 |
| 5.0 | 5.0 |

For each of these, I would generate another column `di` using a UDF `dcalc`:

| x1 | x2 | di |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -5.0 | -5.0 | ? |
| -5.0 | -4.9 | ? |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 5.0 | 5.0 | ? |

Finally, I calculate the sum `dsum` of all the `di` values.

Ultimately, I want to do this over many columns (`x1`...`xN`) and ranges producing dataframes on the order of hundreds of millions or billions of rows.  My code to accomplish this is:

```
import numpy
from scipy import stats
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

eps   = 10.1
iterx = 0.1
sens  = 1
scale = 0.7262317494490057

spark       = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').appName('test').getOrCreate()
sparkRange1 = spark.range(0,101,1)
sparkRange2 = sparkRange1.withColumn('x1',(sparkRange1.id-50)*0.1).drop('id')
sparkRange3 = sparkRange2.crossJoin(sparkRange2.withColumnRenamed('x1', 'x2'))

@udf("float")
def calcd(x1,x2):
    p1 = stats.norm.pdf(x1,loc=0,scale=scale)*            \
         stats.norm.pdf(x2,loc=0,scale=scale)*iterx**2
    p2 = stats.norm.pdf(x1,loc=sens,scale=scale)*         \
         stats.norm.pdf(x2,loc=sens,scale=scale)*iterx**2
    pl = numpy.log(p1/p2)
    if pl > eps:
        d = p1 - numpy.exp(eps) * p2
    else:
        d = 0
    return float(d)

result = sparkRange3.withColumn("di", calcd('x1','x2'))
result.printSchema()
result.show()

dsum = result.agg({'di': 'sum'}).collect()[0][0]
```

Unfortunately, the final `agg` is very slow.  Four columns and ~100M rows takes over an hour given use of 42 cores, but I can calculate the same result in about 30 seconds using C++ on a single core.  I need this to scale, so (Py)Spark seems like it would be a natural fit for the problem.

Is there another approach anyone can recommend?  Is the slowness a result of how I'm creating the input dataframe?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is probably the udf, not the aggregation. UDFs are slow in Spark. Ideally you should rewrite your udf to use native Spark functionality. Second best is to make a pandas_udf.

Comment: @ZygD  Quite right!  I rewrote using native Spark functions, and the performance is much better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the UDF with native Spark functions, and my performance issue is solved.

```
import numpy
from time import perf_counter
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import exp, log, when, lit

eps   = 10.1
iterx = 0.1
sens  = 1
scale = 0.7262317494490057

e_eps = numpy.exp(eps)
inv_sqrt_2pi = 1/numpy.sqrt(2 * numpy.pi)

spark       = SparkSession.builder.master('local[*]').appName('test').getOrCreate()
sparkRange1 = spark.range(0,101,1)
sparkRange2 = sparkRange1.withColumn('x1',(sparkRange1.id-50)*0.1).drop('id')
sparkRange3 = sparkRange2.crossJoin(sparkRange2.withColumnRenamed('x1', 'x2'))

result = sparkRange3.withColumn('p1x1', iterx*inv_sqrt_2pi/scale*exp(-0.5*(sparkRange3.x1 / scale)**2)) \
                    .withColumn('p1x2', iterx*inv_sqrt_2pi/scale*exp(-0.5*(sparkRange3.x2 / scale)**2)) \
                    .withColumn('p2x1', iterx*inv_sqrt_2pi/scale*exp(-0.5*((sparkRange3.x1-sens) / scale)**2)) \
                    .withColumn('p2x2', iterx*inv_sqrt_2pi/scale*exp(-0.5*((sparkRange3.x2-sens) / scale)**2))
result2 = result.withColumn('pl', log((result.p1x1*result.p1x2)/(result.p2x1*result.p2x2)))
result3 = result2.withColumn('di', when(result2.pl > eps, \
                                        result2.p1x1*result2.p1x2-e_eps*result2.p2x1*result2.p2x2) \
                                   .otherwise(lit(0)))

t1 = perf_counter()
result4 = result3.agg({'di':'sum'}).collect()[0][0]
print(result4)
print(perf_counter() - t1)
```

Comment: Maybe you could share the function which you wrote?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).